# Navigation Without Pre-Built Map for Collision-Free Movement

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to design a vehicle to operate in an environment where building the map initially is not feasible.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334028/in-all-the-navigation-tutorials-the-robot-requires-a-pre-built-map.can-i-do-the-navigation-in-an-unknown-environment-without-a-pre-defined-map,so-that-it-moves-without-collision/) by [akshayantony](https://answers.ros.org/users/46257/akshayantony/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-09-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, in 2 ways.

1. You can build a map while your navigating, there's no requiring the map is prebuilt, just if you have one its available. You can navigate fine in SLAM because its still providing the map -> odom transform & also giving you the map image if that's helpful for navigating in your case
2. Nothing in navigation strictly requires a map, you can navigate without a map, just can't use the static layers in your costmap meaningfully

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [akshayantony](https://answers.ros.org/users/46257/akshayantony/) on 2019-10-07**:
so i should launch the move_base without the amcl launch file.If its wrong i am sorry ,i am a beginner in ros.

**Comment by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on 2021-07-27**:
hi,
if I want to use the first approach, navigating while mapping and localization (SLAM), do i need to put rolling-window as TRUE, in both local and global costmap param???