# Challenges with Local Planner in ROS2 Navigation2: Ineffectual Obstacle Avoidance and Potential Self-Detection

Tags: teb-local-planner, nav2, local-costmap, avoid-obstacle, laser-filters

I'm currently facing challenges with the local planner in ROS2's Navigation stack, which is **ineffectively distorting the global plan to avoid obstacles** as displayed in these videos:

[GPS ok But Local Planner does not avoid obstacles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3BiKpJ2GV8)
[Pre mapped spod issue local planner- collision](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-hUfrYxRUVA)

. The behavior observed is that the local planner seems to be caught in a loop, making continuous minor adjustments around the robot's footprint, reminiscent of **a spiral pattern**.
[image]

I'm unsure about the root cause and how to configure the planner for optimal performance properly.

Here's my configuration file for the path planner: https://pastebin.com/5B52hKH4.

I've tried all the documented global planners in nav2: Smac Planner Hybrid, Lattice, Dubins, and Reedshep. My current setup uses the default DWB as the local planner:

```
FollowPath:
  plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
  debug_trajectory_details: True
```

And for the global planner:

```
GridBased:
  plugin:  "nav2_smac_planner/SmacPlannerHybrid"
  downsample_costmap: false
  downsampling_factor: 1
  tolerance: 1.0
  allow_unknown: true
  cost_scaling_factor: 0.9
  neutral_cost: 50
  max_iterations: 1000000
  max_on_approach_iterations: 1000
  max_planning_time: 10.0
  motion_model_for_search:  "DUBIN"
```

One hypothesis I have is that the **LiDARs might be detecting parts of the robot** (e.g., the truck) as obstacles, leading the robot to attempt to **avoid its own "shadow"**. This behavior can be observed in this video [Nav2 Smac Planner: Dubin Ackerman Local Planner Inadequate for Large Truck Robot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tz0ExUVdzPw&t=102s)

[image]

To address this, I attempted **to filter out the scan beams** that detect this part of the truck, hoping it would mitigate the issue. However, this approach didn't yield the desired results, as the robot **still displayed the same erratic behavior**, as shown in this video [Laser Scan Filtering avoid false positives (Error) NAV2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xM4txltYsxA)

[image]

Does anyone have insights or suggestions on **how to effectively configure the local planner to deviate from the global plan for obstacle avoidance?** Filtering the laser scan didn't seem to be effective. Are there other methods or configurations I should consider? Additionally, **has anyone tried using TEB with nav2?** Does it offer better performance in such scenarios? If yes, How to configure it/ integrate it with Nav2?

Comment: I checked that the issue in unrelated to the Lidar false positive detection, as stated in this video description: https://youtu.be/I5RTD0vqJKw.
It is also unrelated to the DWB parameters as I set extensively different values. I WILL CLOSE THIS ISSUE since I did not get any answer or could progress alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely answered here: [Local Planner Not Extending Beyond Robot's Footprint Boundaries to Distort Global Planner's Path](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/104301/local-planner-not-extending-beyond-robots-footprint-boundaries-to-distort-globa/104309#104309)

Result:

[image: Avoiding Obstacles with GPS Follower]
Now, we need fine-tuning to optimize the behavior.