# Local Planner struggling to follow the global plan

Tags: ros2, nav2

When I set the NAV2GOAL in rviz, the global plan displayed and robot initially starts following it. However just after reaching the goal and when an angular goal is set, sometimes the robot tries to follow the path but mostly becomes clueless and freezes at the position. However,I can see the spin behaviour of front wheels on the same position and backup behaviour.

My github issue for full explanation is [Local Planner struggling to follow the global plan #3856](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/3856). I tried tuning some parameters but still the same situation.

Could someone advise?

**Controller and planner server params**

```
  ros__parameters:
    # controller server parameters (see Controller Server for more info)
    use_sim_time: False
    controller_frequency: 5.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker"
    goal_checker_plugins: ["general_goal_checker"]
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0
    # Goal checker parameters
    #precise_goal_checker:
    #  plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
    #  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
    #  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25
    #  stateful: True
    general_goal_checker:
      stateful: True
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.1
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.1
    # DWB parameters
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
      debug_trajectory_details: True
      min_vel_x: 0.0
      min_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_x: 0.26
      max_vel_y: 0.26
      max_vel_theta: 1.0
      min_speed_xy: 0.0
      max_speed_xy: 0.26
      min_speed_theta: 0.0
      # Add high threshold velocity for turtlebot 3 issue.
      # https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/issues/75
      acc_lim_x: 2.5
      acc_lim_y: 2.5
      acc_lim_theta: 3.2
      decel_lim_x: -2.5
      decel_lim_y: -2.5
      decel_lim_theta: -3.2
      vx_samples: 20
      vy_samples: 5
      vtheta_samples: 20
      sim_time: 1.7
      linear_granularity: 0.05
      angular_granularity: 0.025
      transform_tolerance: 0.2
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      trans_stopped_velocity: 0.1
      short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: True
      stateful: True
      critics: ["RotateToGoal", "Oscillation", "BaseObstacle", "GoalAlign", "PathAlign", "PathDist", "GoalDist"]
      BaseObstacle.scale: 0.02
      PathAlign.scale: 32.0
      PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      GoalAlign.scale: 24.0
      GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      PathDist.scale: 32.0
      GoalDist.scale: 24.0
      RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0
      RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
      RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0
      publish_trajectories: true
      publish_local_plan: true

      
controller_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    use_sim_time: False

    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_smac_planner/SmacPlannerHybrid"
      downsample_costmap: false           # whether or not to downsample the map
      downsampling_factor: 1              # multiplier for the resolution of the costmap layer (e.g. 2 on a 5cm costmap would be 10cm)
      tolerance: 0.25                     # dist-to-goal heuristic cost (distance) for valid tolerance endpoints if exact goal cannot be found.
      allow_unknown: true                 # allow traveling in unknown space
      max_iterations: 1000000             # maximum total iterations to search for before failing (in case unreachable), set to -1 to disable
      max_on_approach_iterations: 1000    # Maximum number of iterations after within tolerances to continue to try to find exact solution
      max_planning_time: 5.0              # max time in s for planner to plan, smooth
      motion_model_for_search: "REEDS_SHEPP"    # Hybrid-A* Dubin, Redds-Shepp
      angle_quantization_bins: 72         # Number of angle bins for search
      analytic_expansion_ratio: 3.5       # The ratio to attempt analytic expansions during search for final approach.
      analytic_expansion_max_length: 3.0  # For Hybrid/Lattice nodes: The maximum length of the analytic expansion to be considered valid to prevent unsafe shortcutting
      minimum_turning_radius: 1.0        # minimum turning radius in m of path / vehicle
      reverse_penalty: 2.0                # Penalty to apply if motion is reversing, must be => 1
      change_penalty: 0.0                 # Penalty to apply if motion is changing directions (L to R), must be >= 0
      non_straight_penalty: 1.2           # Penalty to apply if motion is non-straight, must be => 1
      cost_penalty: 2.0                   # Penalty to apply to higher cost areas when adding into the obstacle map dynamic programming distance expansion heuristic. This drives the robot more towards the center of passages. A value between 1.3 - 3.5 is reasonable.
      retrospective_penalty: 0.015
      lookup_table_size: 20.0             # Size of the dubin/reeds-sheep distance window to cache, in meters.
      cache_obstacle_heuristic: false     # Cache the obstacle map dynamic programming distance expansion heuristic between subsiquent replannings of the same goal location. Dramatically speeds up replanning performance (40x) if costmap is largely static.
      smooth_path: True                   # If true, does a simple and quick smoothing post-processing to the path

      smoother:
        max_iterations: 1000
        w_smooth: 0.3
        w_data: 0.2
        tolerance: 1.0e-10
        do_refinement: true
        refinement_num: 2
        
planner_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
```

**local and global costmap params**

```
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: False
      rolling_window: true
      width: 5
      height: 5
      resolution: 0.05
      robot_radius: 0.5
      plugins: ["obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 1.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 6.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 1.0
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  local_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
  local_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
#global costmap configurations
global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: false
      robot_radius: 0.5
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: true
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 6.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 1.0
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 1.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  global_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
  global_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
```

Comment: What kind of wheel-drive configuration does your robot have? (e.g. Differential, Ackermann, or Holonomic?)

Comment: @Mike973
its Ackermann. So, I tried with Smac Planner A* Hybrid

Comment: It seems to me that it's more likely the Local Planner causes the behavior you describe. Are you sure that your DWBLocalPlanner can be used with Ackermann drive?

Comment: From what I am seeing, robot is able to reach the goal However when I set the goal in a reverse direction, the robot do not reverse and follow that path. I might make that work with running behavior server backup but isn't the smac planner and controller should do this instead. One thing I might thinking is my robot world is bit conjusted and the costmaps are coming in the planing path due to which the robot stucks sometimes. I tried to tune the params where I could.

Comment: I think I got it. It was just to set the min_vel_x param in DWB controller to some negative value,  say (-0.5) and then it seems to follow the global plan. It was a foolish thing which got ignored.